# SQL Merging two rows into a single Row

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am trying to run the SQL to merge two rows into one, but I am having trouble in getting the output I desire.

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Acct](
    [Account_ID] [nchar](10) NULL,
    [Account_Type] [nchar](10) NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[ETF](
    [ETF_ID] [nchar](10) NULL,
    [ETF_Name] [nchar](10) NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Fund](
    [Fund_ID] [nchar](10) NULL,
    [Fund_Name] [nchar](10) NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Rel](
    [Rel_Account_ID] [nchar](10) NULL,
    [Rel_Fund_ETF_ID] [nchar](10) NULL,
    [Row_id] [nchar](10) NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]

INSERT [dbo].[Acct] ([Account_ID], [Account_Type]) VALUES (N'ZA001T12  ', N'INDV      ')
INSERT [dbo].[Acct] ([Account_ID], [Account_Type]) VALUES (N'ZA001T09  ', N'INDV      ')

INSERT [dbo].[ETF] ([ETF_ID], [ETF_Name]) VALUES (N'FUETAR    ', N'ETFAR     ')

INSERT [dbo].[Fund] ([Fund_ID], [Fund_Name]) VALUES (N'FUESPY    ', N'FNSPY     ')
INSERT [dbo].[Fund] ([Fund_ID], [Fund_Name]) VALUES (N'FUFSPY    ', N'FUFSPY    ')

INSERT [dbo].[Rel] ([Rel_Account_ID], [Rel_Fund_ETF_ID], [Row_id]) VALUES (N'ZA001T12  ', N'FUESPY    ', N'1         ')
INSERT [dbo].[Rel] ([Rel_Account_ID], [Rel_Fund_ETF_ID], [Row_id]) VALUES (N'ZA001T12  ', N'FUETAR    ', N'2         ')
INSERT [dbo].[Rel] ([Rel_Account_ID], [Rel_Fund_ETF_ID], [Row_id]) VALUES (N'ZA001T09  ', N'FUESPX    ', N'3         ')
INSERT [dbo].[Rel] ([Rel_Account_ID], [Rel_Fund_ETF_ID], [Row_id]) VALUES (N'ZA001T12  ', N'FUFSPY    ', N'4         ')
```

The SQL suggested from @Dale K/Gudwlk works perfectly for 1:1 relationship with one Account ID having 1 Fund, but if there are more than one row in relationship table then the additional data gets missed from the output.

Ideally, I want to generate the output as below for accounts that have more than 1 funds/ETF, by having additional Fund_ID's and ETF_Ids'.(Not sure if this is really possible now having 1:M relationship in Fund/ETF):

| Acc_ID | Acc_Typ | Rl_Acc_ID | Fnd_ID_1 | ETF_ID | Fnd_ID_2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ZA0001T12 | INDIV | ZA001T12 | FUESPY | FUETAR | FUFSPY |

Would really appreciate for any insights of the feasibilty for the above representation or the (only) possible alternatives.

Thanks

PS:
Getting the following output by removing the WHERE condition from the main SQL as suggested by @Gudwlk. When I add all the three conditions then I am getting no rows.

| Account_ID | Account_Type | Rel_Account_ID | Fund_ID_1 | ETF_id | Fund_id_2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ZA001T09 | INDV | ZA001T09 | NULL | NULL | NULL |
| ZA001T12 | INDV | ZA001T12 | FUESPY | NULL | FUFSPY |
| ZA001T12 | INDV | ZA001T12 | FUFSPY | NULL | NULL |
| ZA001T12 | INDV | ZA001T12 | NULL | FUETAR | NULL |

Comment: can you add data and DDL s to try ?

Comment: If you add your sample data as DDL+DML you make it much easier for us.

Comment: @SathyaKumar this join doesnot work with your data. in the second row, you should get ETF_id. it is not now.  LEFT OUTER JOIN ETF E ON R.Rel_Fund_ETF_ID = E.ETF_id

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think you want a `union` rather another `join`. Note the use of table aliases for clarity.

```
declare @Acct table (Account_ID varchar(12), Account_Type varchar(12));

insert into @Acct (Account_ID, Account_Type)
values
('ZA0001T12', 'INDIV');

declare @Rel table (Rel_Account_ID varchar(12), Rel_Fund_ETF_ID varchar(12));

insert into @Rel (Rel_Account_ID, Rel_Fund_ETF_ID)
values
('ZA0001T12', 'FUESPY'),
('ZA0001T12', 'FUETAR');

declare @Etf table (ETF_ID varchar(12), ETF_NAME varchar(12));

insert into @Etf (ETF_ID, ETF_NAME)
values
('FUETAR', 'ETFAR');

declare @Fund table (FUND_ID varchar(12), Fund_NAME varchar(12));

insert into @Fund (FUND_ID, Fund_NAME)
values
('FUESPY','FNSPY');

SELECT A.Account_ID, A.Account_Type, R.Rel_Account_ID, MAX(F.FUND_ID) FUND_ID, MAX(E.ETF_ID) ETF_ID
FROM @Acct A
LEFT JOIN @Rel R ON R.Rel_Account_ID = A.Account_ID
LEFT JOIN @Fund F ON F.Fund_id = R.Rel_Fund_ETF_ID
LEFT JOIN @ETF E ON E.ETF_ID = R.Rel_Fund_ETF_ID
GROUP BY A.Account_ID, A.Account_Type, R.Rel_Account_ID;
```

FYI: When you do come to use `union` in almost all circumstances you want `union all` because it performs better.

Note also: if you provide DDL+DML (as I have done) you make it much easier for people to answer.

Comment: Thanks for your response, but when I try to run the above I am not fetching any rows.

Comment: Are you sure that the above two records are coming from two queries or from the same query. if the above two records come from same query, then the after adding an inner join will result with no data. To try please provide sample data at least a portion. not all. @SathyaKumar. if the second join added as subquery to select list, sometimes you can have your result.

Comment: @Dale K Thanks for your comments. I provided the table structure and the sample row.

Comment: @Gudwlk - Thanks for your response. I updated the post with sample row and the table structure.

Answer (score 0):

```
 CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Acct](
    [Account_ID] [nchar](10) NULL,
    [Account_Type] [nchar](10) NULL
 ) ON [PRIMARY]

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[ETF](
   [ETF_ID] [nchar](10) NULL,
   [ETF_Name] [nchar](10) NULL
 ) ON [PRIMARY]

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Fund](
   [Fund_ID] [nchar](10) NULL,
   [Fund_Name] [nchar](10) NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Rel](
    [Rel_Account_ID] [nchar](10) NULL,
    [Rel_Fund_ETF_ID] [nchar](10) NULL,
    [Row_id] [nchar](10) NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]



INSERT [dbo].[Acct] ([Account_ID], [Account_Type]) VALUES (N'ZA001T12', N'INDV')
INSERT [dbo].[Acct] ([Account_ID], [Account_Type]) VALUES (N'ZA001T09', N'INDV')

INSERT [dbo].[ETF] ([ETF_ID], [ETF_Name]) VALUES (N'FUETAR', N'ETFAR')

INSERT [dbo].[Fund] ([Fund_ID], [Fund_Name]) VALUES (N'FUESPY', N'FNSPY')
INSERT [dbo].[Fund] ([Fund_ID], [Fund_Name]) VALUES (N'FUFSPY', N'FUFSPY')

INSERT [dbo].[Rel] ([Rel_Account_ID], [Rel_Fund_ETF_ID], [Row_id]) VALUES (N'ZA001T12', N'FUESPY', N'1')
INSERT [dbo].[Rel] ([Rel_Account_ID], [Rel_Fund_ETF_ID], [Row_id]) VALUES (N'ZA001T12', N'FUETAR', N'2')
INSERT [dbo].[Rel] ([Rel_Account_ID], [Rel_Fund_ETF_ID], [Row_id]) VALUES (N'ZA001T09', N'FUESPX', N'3')
INSERT [dbo].[Rel] ([Rel_Account_ID], [Rel_Fund_ETF_ID], [Row_id]) VALUES (N'ZA001T12', N'FUFSPY', N'4')

SELECT 
   BC.Account_ID
 , BC.Account_Type
 , BC.Rel_Account_ID
 , BC.FundId AS Fund_ID_1
 , BC.ETF_id
 , BC.Fund_id_2
FROM
 (
SELECT
  AB.Account_ID
 , AB.Account_Type
 , AB.Rel_Account_ID
 , AB.Fund_ID as FundId
 , CASE WHEN AB.ETF_Id IS NULL THEN  LAG (ETF_Id) over (partition by  AB.Account_ID
 , AB.Account_Type
 , AB.Rel_Account_ID Order by  AB.Account_ID ) ELSE AB.ETF_Id END as ETF_id
 , ROW_NUMBER () over (partition by  AB.Account_ID, AB.Account_Type
 , AB.Rel_Account_ID Order by  AB.Account_ID ) AS row_id
 , AB.Fund_id_2
FROM
  (
  Select   A.Account_ID
  , A.Account_Type
  , R.Rel_Account_ID 
  , F.FUND_ID
  , E.ETF_ID
  , R.Row_id
  , R.Rel_Fund_ETF_ID
  , CASE WHEN ( SELECT COUNT(1)  FROM  Fund FD WHERE R.Rel_Fund_ETF_ID = FD.Fund_id ) = 1 THEN LEAD(F.FUND_ID)  OVER (Order by Fund_id)  END AS Fund_id_2
   FROM Rel R 
        INNER JOIN Acct A ON R.Rel_Account_ID = A.Account_ID 
        LEFT outer JOIN  Fund F ON  R.Rel_Fund_ETF_ID = F.Fund_id
        LEFT OUTER JOIN ETF E ON R.Rel_Fund_ETF_ID = E.ETF_id    
    ) AS AB
  ) AS BC
 WHERE BC.ETF_id IS NOT NULL
 AND BC.FundId IS NOT NULL 
 AND BC.Fund_id_2 IS NOT NULL
```

[image: Result]

Comment: @SathyaKumar try now. I added one possible solution

Comment: Thanks you all for the quick solution, but noticed if I have two rows in the Relation table like below, then the query is ignoring the first and showing only the Max. Ideally there will be only one Account ---> with 1 Fund and 1 EFT, but there is a possibility for max 2 to be there in the relation ship table and in the fund table. Will update my original post with the DDL/DML statement.

Comment: if you add original data with possible scenario, i can give the query. and please add the expected output too. it will be easy then. Thanks @SathyaKumar. Happy to help

Comment: @SathyaKumar Answer is modified and have a look and let me know if you need further changes. Thank you

Comment: The answer needs some modification. Ill add once I get some time. Please leave this as it is.  I just saw your updated answer. Give me a little time. @SathyaKumar

Comment: @SathyaKumar Can you have a look in the answer. Meanwhile ill try to provide a simple one as well.

Comment: Thanks@Gudwlk...the output is having the new column Fund_id2 but the data is showing 'FUESPY', I would expect to see as 'FUFSPY'. Thanks for the solution though I wouldn't have come up with that.

Comment: @SathyaKumar yeah. ill check this and update asap. thanks. I didnt notice this

Comment: @SathyaKumar I changed. have a look

Comment: Not sure what was wrong from my end , when I ran the SQL I am getting no rows returned.

Comment: @SathyaKumar I added data and table details in the answer. Please check your data and mine are same. Can you check without the where clause or comment and uncomment one by one in where clause to see what is wrong. this can be a data issue. I get the output for above tables. Let me know.

Comment: @DaleK The last image is related to show somethin that I cannot describe. With the given data I can see the answer. So I wanted to show this to Post owner. Thanks for information

Comment: @SathyaKumar  I found the issue. When you run with your above provided DDL and data statements you will get the results. Your data , Fund and rel tabes are not matching. Ill explain this tomorrow. I am stuck with a work

Comment: @SathyaKumar use the above provided data and check. I did not change any. have a look

Comment: @Gudwlk there is nothing in your image that cannot be displayed as text.

Comment: @Gudwlk Thanks much, after dropping my tables and recreating with your DDL and inserting the data your SQL worked. Much curious to know what's the issue with my data. Thanks again.

Comment: I will check the issue and get back to you. If the solution works, can you accept my answer and give me a vote? I see this as a data issue.

Comment: @SathyaKumar this join doesnot work with your data. in the second row, you should get ETF_id. it is not now.  LEFT OUTER JOIN ETF E ON R.Rel_Fund_ETF_ID = E.ETF_id

Comment: if you can extract the first select section data I can have a look. 
and if the above selection gives you result, can you accept it and give me a vote? Thanks

Comment: @Gudwlk , The results work and  thanks for your help. I upvoted but for some reason my vote is not getting picked up.

Comment: @DaleK - Thanks, I accepted the checkmark.

Comment: @SathyaKumar did you reject the answer?

Comment: @SathyaKumar why did you change vote? the answer accepted does not provide correct results. :(